# Increase Accuracy of float division (python)

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm writing a bit of code in PyCharm, and I want the division to be much more accurate than it currently is (40-50 numbers instead of about 15). How Can I accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at http://mpmath.org/

Comment: Make sure this is actually a solution to your problem. Increasing the precision won't solve most rounding error issues, and if you actually need to know the 40th digit of your result, you still might get results like `20.9999999...[30 more digits]92593847343` instead of `21`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/decimal.html) module:

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> getcontext().prec = 50
>>> Decimal(1)/Decimal(7)
Decimal('0.14285714285714285714285714285714285714285714285714')
```

If you're interested in more sophisticated operations than `decimal` provides, you can also look at libraries like [`bigfloat`](https://pythonhosted.org/bigfloat/), or [`mpmath`](http://mpmath.org/) (which I use, and like a lot.)