# How does Python divide really big integers?

Tags: python

In python 3 you can divide two integers with 1000 digits each and it will return a float. I am trying to understand what accuracy is guaranteed in the result.

> What is the precise method/algorithm that Python uses to divide 1000 digit integers? Also, what guarantees are there about the accuracy of the result?

The question [Increase Accuracy of float division (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112891/increase-accuracy-of-float-division-python) is not the same as this one as it didn't ask for the precise method/algorithm used by python 3 to divide large integers. Also the answer provided simply points the OP to a different module.

Comment: There is some info about this in the Python docs here: https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: @OferSadan I have edited the question to explain why that question is different.

Comment: @JackTaylor Thanks but I didn't see any discussion of how very large integers are divided there. Did I miss it?

Comment: @Anush agreed, I'm retracting my "duplicate" comment

Comment: It doesn't discuss the exact division algorithm, but it does discuss the accuracy of the result (the part about IEEE-754 doubles having 53 bits of precision).

Comment: @JackTaylor True. But without knowing how it divides huge integers it's hard to understand how accurate the result will be.

Comment: The language spec does not appear to give any guarantees how ``truediv(:int, :int)`` works. As for how the current version of CPython does it, the algorithm is documented in the source code: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4be11c009abe88175fa164b45e4838e7267dfa97/Objects/longobject.c#L3894